# Google Recapcha V3 actions, what it is

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

hi i would like to know how to use attribute **action** in google recapcha API V3 i cant find what exaclty it is

[Google API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

already tried check API docs but without any progress :\ thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems action can be anything you like, it just acts as a way to distinguish different functions you might have captcha for. Example, one action to monitor sign in activity, one to monitor posting text, etc

Comment: The [library/API](https://github.com/google/ReCAPTCHA#usage) allows you to verify an action with `setExpectedAction()` – can you define it somewhere in the [Google backend](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/)? I don't see anything.